# How to connect node server via apache?

Tags: node.js, angular, apache, seo, server-side-rendering

We have angular application running in apache and jboss servers in CSR approach. Now we are moving to SSR approach to implement SEO.

So we are trying like request should go to Apache then redirect to nodejs and then jboss.

In box1, apache has been installed.
In box2, nodejs and jboss has been installed.

I have tried like proxypass /node http://:/node. But it is throwing proxy error "The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server."

Aapche version : 2.4
node : v11.5.0
npm : 6.4.1
Angular CLI: 6.1.5

Much appreciate if anyone could help us.

Suggest if any other approach is there to implement SEO. 
PS: we can't replace apache and jboss with other servers.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need SEO, try to use [prerender](https://prerender.io). It also has solutions for [apache](https://prerender.io/documentation/install-middleware#apache) and much more